# Magnetic circuit and material magnetization

Tags: magnetics, ferrite

We have a high power magnet (SmCo, 1T) whose field is being conducted through EN24T steel to an airgap where we perform measurements.

The problem is that there appears to be a creeping change in field strength over time in the gap which we are attributing to the slow magnetization of the steel. I would guess that we need a material that either fully saturates at a lower field strength than the magnet, or something that does not exhibit this slow magnetization. Ferrites spring to mind, but not sure of what type or whether that would be the only option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you allow the steel to become fully magnetized, it would stop changing with time.

Comment: @Hearth I just found out that it appears to be demagnetizing with time. Going to try degaussing it to start with